# How will I pass values from router to controller in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I want to pass app.locals values into a controller function. How will I pass the variable inside the controller.

```
var enroll_controller=require('../enrollController');
    router.post('/enroll',function(req,res){
        var contractAddress=req.app.locals.contractAddress;
        enroll_controller.newUser
    });
```

I want to pass contractAddress to enroll_controller?
Anybody?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass it as middleware:

```
router.post('/enroll',enroll_controller.newUser);
```

And in your controller function you can directly use it like this:

```
exports.newUser=function(req,res){
var contractAddress=req.app.locals.contractAddress
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this too if you don't want to use middleware.

```
var enroll_controller=require('../enrollController');
router.post('/enroll',function(req,res){
    enroll_controller.newUser(req,res);
});
```

## enrollCntroller.js

```
exports.newuser=function(req,res){
  var contractAddress=req.app.locals.contractAddress
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a global middleware and set these values in that middleware if you want it to be available for every route.

```
// in your app.js file or main file which is wiring up application
app.use(function(req,res,next){
 req.app.locals.contractAddress = "Set address here."
 next();
});

var enroll_controller=require('../enrollController');
router.post('/enroll',enroll_controller.newUser);
```

or you can export run the above middleware to only one route and set address for that specific route.

```
    var enroll_controller=require('../enrollController');
    router.post('/enroll',
     function(req,res, next){
        // middleware running to one route only. 
        req.app.locals.contractAddress = 'set address here';        
        next();
     },
     enroll_controller.newUser
    );
```

You can also export this middleware from a file and then reuse it instead of defining for every time as anonymous function.